# Override VideoJS PlayProgressBar

Tags: javascript, angular, video.js

I'm trying to overwrite a component of VideoJs in such a way that it uses a custom function:

Portion of code in video.js:

```
var PlayProgressBar = function (_Component) {
inherits(PlayProgressBar, _Component);

...

PlayProgressBar.prototype.update = function update(seekBarRect, seekBarPoint) {

...


 this.rafId_ = this.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    var time = _this2.player_.scrubbing() ? _this2.player_.getCache().currentTime : _this2.player_.currentTime();

    var content = formatTime(time, _this2.player_.duration());
    var timeTooltip = _this2.getChild('timeTooltip');

    if (timeTooltip) {
      timeTooltip.update(seekBarRect, seekBarPoint, content);
    }
  });
};

return PlayProgressBar;


 }(Component);
```

Point of interest:

```
this.rafId_ = this.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    var time = _this2.player_.scrubbing() ? _this2.player_.getCache().currentTime : _this2.player_.currentTime();

    var content = formatTime(time, _this2.player_.duration());
    var timeTooltip = _this2.getChild('timeTooltip');

    if (timeTooltip) {
      timeTooltip.update(seekBarRect, seekBarPoint, content);
    }
  });
```

Change in Point of interest (CUSTOMFUNCTION):

```
this.rafId_ = this.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    var time = _this2.player_.scrubbing() ? _this2.player_.getCache().currentTime : _this2.player_.currentTime();

    var content = CUSTOMFUNCTION(time, _this2.player_.duration());
    var timeTooltip = _this2.getChild('timeTooltip');

    if (timeTooltip) {
      timeTooltip.update(seekBarRect, seekBarPoint, content);
    }
  });
```

I can't override the original video.js file, so i'm trying to override it with

```
videojs.getComponent("PlayProgressBar").f...
```

But I'm not succeeding. What can i do?

Comment: Can't you include another js file just below Video.js where you override "var PlayProgressBar = function (_Component) {" at loading time..

Comment: @numbtongue It doens't work